# Sharepoint User Favorite Documents

Tags: c#, sharepoint, document-library

Our Sharepoint site functions as a sort of document library, with users able to browse but not edit any document added. What would be really useful is if users were able to individually mark as a document as their "favorite" and then have a list somewhere so they could go back to see it. Is there a "feature" or a custom extension that would allow for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a document library, they open the context menu on a document and do "add to my links" and it will show up in the links list on their MySite. They can make a category "favorite docs".

You do need MOSS for this function not just WSS.